# Catch two notifications in android

Tags: android

I am creating notifications with following code:

```
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.top_icon)
                            .setContentText(senderName)
                            .setTicker(senderName+" ")
                            .setSound(soundUri);
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("gcm_username",senderName);
                    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(NotificationID.getID(senderName), mBuilder.build());
```

When user clicks the notification I am catching it with following code in loginActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    gcmUserId= getIntent().getStringExtra("gcm_username");
    startAction(gcmUserId);
....
```

My problem starts here.

**Scenario:**

1)When app is closed user receives notifications from 2 different users

2)User clicks first notification and app starts then `startAction` method calls.

3)Then user clicks the second notification

But when user clicks the second notification app has already started so `startAction` won't be able to call again because it is in the `onCreate` method.How can catch second notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it inside [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)). You would need to override that method inside your activity. The docs say:

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, **when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.**